# C# Json Deserialization fails

Tags: c#, arrays, json, serialization

I'm trying to make an application that can show local TV guide trough JSON rest api C #, but has some problems with deserialization of my Json response.

i'm only intresest in the array NOW in my json call and i do not own the api service.

I get this error message:

> An exception of type 'Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException' occurred in Newtonsoft.Json.DLL but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: Cannot deserialize the current JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) into type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[TDC_Play_TV_Mobil.superclass2+Now]' because the type requires a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) to deserialize correctly.
>
> To fix this error either change the JSON to a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) or change the deserialized type so that it is a normal .NET type (e.g. not a primitive type like integer, not a collection type like an array or List) that can be deserialized from a JSON object. JsonObjectAttribute can also be added to the type to force it to deserialize from a JSON object.
>
> Path 'now', line 1, position 7.

My function:

```
private HttpClient client;

   public async Task<List<superclass2.Now>> GetComments()
   {
       client = new HttpClient();
      var response = await client.GetAsync(new Uri("http://api.yousee.tv/rest/tvguide/nowandnext/"));
       if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
       {
           
           string json = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

           System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(json);
           var task = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<superclass2.Now>>(json));

           var value = await task;
         //  List<superclass2.Now> comments = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<superclass2.Now>>(await json);
          System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Comments er lavet");
          return value;

       }
       else
       {
           throw new Exception("Errorhandling message");

       }
        

   }
```

My class file:

```
public class superclass2
{
public class Logos
   {
       public string small { get; set; }
       public string large { get; set; }
       public string small_seapp { get; set; }
       public string large_seapp { get; set; }
       public string extralarge { get; set; }
       public string super { get; set; }
       public string mega { get; set; }
       public string netgem { get; set; }
       public string svg { get; set; }
   }

   public class ChannelInfo
   {
       public string name { get; set; }
       public string shortname { get; set; }
       public string logo_image_prefix { get; set; }
       public Logos logos { get; set; }
       public int archivedays { get; set; }
       public string channelcolor { get; set; }
   }

   public class FormattedDate
   {
       public string time_begin { get; set; }
       public string time_end { get; set; }
       public string date { get; set; }
   }

   public class ImagesSixteenbynine
   {
       public string large { get; set; }
       public string medium { get; set; }
       public string small { get; set; }
   }

   public class ImagesFourbythree
   {
       public string large { get; set; }
       public string small { get; set; }
   }

   public class ImagesSquare
   {
       public string large { get; set; }
       public string medium { get; set; }
       public string small { get; set; }
   }

   public class Now
   {
       public int id { get; set; }
       public int dvb_id { get; set; }
       public int channel { get; set; }
       public ChannelInfo channel_info { get; set; }
       public string orgtitle { get; set; }
       public string cast { get; set; }
       public string directors { get; set; }
       public string series_info { get; set; }
       public int series_id { get; set; }
       public string series_name { get; set; }
       public bool allowseriesrecording { get; set; }
       public int totalinarchive { get; set; }
       public int popularity_score { get; set; }
       public int totalupcoming { get; set; }
       public int category { get; set; }
       public int subcategory { get; set; }
       public string category_string { get; set; }
       public string subcategory_string { get; set; }
       public int begin { get; set; }
       public object actual_begin { get; set; }
       public int end { get; set; }
       public int actual_end { get; set; }
       public int tvdate { get; set; }
       public FormattedDate formatted_date { get; set; }
       public string title { get; set; }
       public string description { get; set; }
       public bool archive { get; set; }
       public bool scrubbingallowed { get; set; }
       public int expiresfromarchive { get; set; }
       public bool startover { get; set; }
       public string imageprefix { get; set; }
       public ImagesSixteenbynine images_sixteenbynine { get; set; }
       public ImagesFourbythree images_fourbythree { get; set; }
       public ImagesSquare images_square { get; set; }
       public List<object> decorations { get; set; }
   }

   public class Logos2
   {
       public string small { get; set; }
       public string large { get; set; }
       public string small_seapp { get; set; }
       public string large_seapp { get; set; }
       public string extralarge { get; set; }
       public string super { get; set; }
       public string mega { get; set; }
       public string netgem { get; set; }
       public string svg { get; set; }
   }

   public class ChannelInfo2
   {
       public string name { get; set; }
       public string shortname { get; set; }
       public string logo_image_prefix { get; set; }
       public Logos2 logos { get; set; }
       public int archivedays { get; set; }
       public string channelcolor { get; set; }
   }

   public class FormattedDate2
   {
       public string time_begin { get; set; }
       public string time_end { get; set; }
       public string date { get; set; }
   }

   public class ImagesSixteenbynine2
   {
       public string large { get; set; }
       public string medium { get; set; }
       public string small { get; set; }
   }

   public class ImagesFourbythree2
   {
       public string large { get; set; }
       public string small { get; set; }
   }

   public class ImagesSquare2
   {
       public string large { get; set; }
       public string medium { get; set; }
       public string small { get; set; }
   }

   public class Next
   {
       public int id { get; set; }
       public int dvb_id { get; set; }
       public int channel { get; set; }
       public ChannelInfo2 channel_info { get; set; }
       public string orgtitle { get; set; }
       public string cast { get; set; }
       public string directors { get; set; }
       public string series_info { get; set; }
       public int series_id { get; set; }
       public string series_name { get; set; }
       public bool allowseriesrecording { get; set; }
       public int totalinarchive { get; set; }
       public int popularity_score { get; set; }
       public int totalupcoming { get; set; }
       public int category { get; set; }
       public int subcategory { get; set; }
       public string category_string { get; set; }
       public string subcategory_string { get; set; }
       public int begin { get; set; }
       public int actual_begin { get; set; }
       public int end { get; set; }
       public int actual_end { get; set; }
       public int tvdate { get; set; }
       public FormattedDate2 formatted_date { get; set; }
       public string title { get; set; }
       public string description { get; set; }
       public bool archive { get; set; }
       public bool scrubbingallowed { get; set; }
       public int expiresfromarchive { get; set; }
       public bool startover { get; set; }
       public string imageprefix { get; set; }
       public ImagesSixteenbynine2 images_sixteenbynine { get; set; }
       public ImagesFourbythree2 images_fourbythree { get; set; }
       public ImagesSquare2 images_square { get; set; }
       public List<object> decorations { get; set; }
   }

   public class RootObject
   {
       public List<Now> now { get; set; }
       public List<Next> next { get; set; }
   }

}
```

Comment: When you debugged your code? Could you see at what point the exception thrown? Which value he has trouble with? First try it with a dedicated small peace of JSON.

Comment: Looks like your JSON is incorrect - you're expecting a `List<Now>`, but you've actually got an object instead of a list. I'd also strongly recommend getting rid of `superclass2` - nested types are only going to confuse the matter.

Comment: The exception is throwned at "JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<superclass2.Now>>(json)"

Comment: I can make the Json work in PHP but not in C# so the JSON is right as some point, but could the Nested NOW and NEXT be a problem?

Comment: Please show us the (first few lines of) the json string you're trying to deserialize

Comment: Here are some few lines

{"now":[{"id":-120362552,"dvb_id":20526,"channel":1,"channel_info":{"name":"DR1","shortname":"DR1","logo_image_prefix":"http:\/\/cloud.yousee.tv\/static\/img\/logos\/","logos":{"small":"Small_DR_1.png","large":"Large_DR_1.png","small_seapp":"Seapp_Small_DR_1.png","large_seapp":"Seapp_Large_DR_1.png","extralarge":"IK_DR_1.png","super":"","mega":"","netgem":"Netgem_DR1.png","svg":""},"archivedays":30,"channelcolor":""},"orgtitle":"","cast":"","directors":"","series_info":"","series_id":0,"series_name":"","allowseriesrecording":false,"totalinarchive":0,"pop

Comment: The hole respons is here http://pastebin.com/LDDtMfkt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your JSON isn't a `List<superclass2.Now>`, it's a `superclass2.RootObject`.  So you need to do something like:

```
    public async Task<List<superclass2.Now>> GetComments()    
    {
        client = new HttpClient();
        var response = await client.GetAsync(new Uri("http://api.yousee.tv/rest/tvguide/nowandnext/"));
        if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            string json = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(json);
            var task = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<superclass2.RootObject>(json));

            var value = await task;
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Comments er lavet");
            return (value == null ? null : value.now);
        }
        else
        {
            throw new Exception("Errorhandling message");
        }
    }
```

Agree with Jon Skeet it would be nicer to eliminate the nesting of classes, purely for improved readability.  If you need these classes to exist only in a specific scope, it is better to use [nested namespaces](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/dfb3cx8s%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).  They aren't causing your bug, however.